# Typescript: Pass a union type to an overloaded function?

Tags: typescript

I have this class:

```
type Params = {
    data: string | string[]
}

class Test {
    data: string | string[]

    constructor(params: Params) {
        this.data = this.initData(params.data)
    }

    initData(data: string): string
    initData(data: string[]): string[]
    initData(data: string | string[]): string | string[] {
        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            return data as string
        } else {
            return data as string[]
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(data: string): string', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(data: string[]): string[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.ts(2769)

Untitled-1(38, 5): The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.
```

I found a stupid workaround that helps:

```
constructor(params: Params) {
    this.data = this.initData(params.data)

    if (typeof params.data === 'string') {
        this.data = this.initData(params.data)
    }
    else {
        this.data = this.initData(params.data)
    }
}
```

And I kinda get why this works, but maybe there is a better way to solve this?

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your implementation of `initData` to be just `return data`, since that's all it does and it doesn't affect your question one way or the other... right now it's just distracting (why the type assertions and why two `return data` lines?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107) to support calling an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with an appropriate [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its arguments.  That is, to *distribute* overload resolution over unions of argument types.  For now it's not part of the language and there are only workarounds.

If you want to call an overloaded function today you must make sure the call is appropriate for at least one of its call signatures.  So the most common workaround is to add the missing call signature corresponding to your failed call:

```
class Test {
  data: string | string[]

  constructor(params: Params) {
    this.data = this.initData(params.data)
  }

  // call signatures
  initData(data: string): string
  initData(data: string[]): string[]
  initData(data: string | string[]): string | string[]; // <-- add this

  // implementation
  initData(data: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    return data
  }
}
```

---

That's easy enough to do here because you only have to add one more call signature.  But if you had  call signatures to start with, combining every possible collection of them would result in something on the order of **2** call signatures.  That grows *very* quickly with .  To avoid that exponential growth you could have just a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature that uses [a distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to compute the return type:

```
class Test {
  data: string | string[]

  constructor(params: Params) {
    this.data = this.initData(params.data)
  }

  // call signature
  initData<T extends string | string[]>(data: T): 
    T extends string ? string :
    T extends string[] ? string[] :
    never;

  // implementation
  initData(data: string | string[]): string | string[] {
    return data
  }
}
```

Now the single call signature can automatically distribute over unions and it scales linearly with the number of original call signatures.  It's still *implemented* as an overload, though, because the compiler isn't currently able to verify the bodies of functions returning generic conditional types. See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for a discussion about that.  So we are using the "looseness" of overloaded function implementation to avoid type assertions here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4FgBQUUAJnMHAFxSrAICWAdgOZQA+1tjTA2gLoEBfAgQDGAGzip0AFQg0cBIqXJUa9Zmw7qe-fIqgiA9gzUBXEcEMIAFGEQpUVeEjQBKBYSJRgACzqoAOmU4TG8-QMY6YAARMjhbezQguNd9IT1PAHpMgzgxMWo6JgYyUwQ5fUiYuOtg1U5mV3rtSoYo2PJauOauPiatXt0iKo74uoGNdjVB-unJiZ0AbihsqAAeAFoNqDhiYh2wMARDI7oyaBE8gtQikuAyiH1VumQwMQhkCAZyYDpjVvaNXGcxYUwaOlm4M0IL4Hi8UHK9wQDBIcTSgmEGXEkhkcmAACY4aiVAtoeC+JiiEYTLRzJYbHYXI5YIlUO48J4iL5-MlyKFuRE2tVOoyHLy4KlPOknjlLvlCsVSuUAcK4GtpFAIAAPYBfYjoEFk7R8AB8XRJ0n6+iIGu1uoY+tJAH5SRRrVBbTq9QbybwoC6YX63ZyoAwIAA3CAIRaUlY5F5vD5fH5-Bgq0bmyiksHG3iQ7RGwZEoiIsoo4Lo-ACIA)

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for such detailed answer!

Comment: Thank you for this and all your work on TypeScript! Just got done reading a related issue on GitHub you've participated in :)

Comment: What a great solution! I just wanted to add that it is also possible to skip the type condition and simply return `T` in the call signature since Typescript already infers the type passed to `data` so `T` is already equal to whatever type you pass to `data`. In short, `initData<T extends string | string[]>(data: T): T` should also work as call signature.